# Is there a TreeSet data structure equivalent in C++ with similar functions

Tags: java, c++, data-structures, set, treeset

I need to use a Tree Set data structure(available in java) in C++, and make use of functions like TreeSet.lower(i) and TreeSet.higher(i) - > which returns the element just lower, and just higher than i in the given tree set. Is there an STL?

Edit: 
Following is the functionality I need, I was wondering how to use the upper_bound and lower_bound functions to do it:

```
for (int i = 1; i<10; i++) myset.insert(i * 10); // 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90
int k = 50;  // I need 40 and 60
set<int>::iterator itr = myset.find(k);

if (itr != myset.end()) {
    // Found the element
    itr--; // Previous element;
    cout << *(itr); //prints 40
    itr++; // the element found
    itr++; // The next element
    cout << *(itr);  // prints 60
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`std::set`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/), which is typically implemented as a binary search tree.

Its `insert()`, `erase()` and `find()` methods are logarithmic in size, but can do better if a hint is given. The logarithmic complexity is reffered to the the [Java TreeSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html).

I think you should be interested in [`std::lower_bound`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/lower_bound/), which returns an iterator to the lower bound, and in [`std::upper_bound`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/upper_bound/), which returns an iterator to the upper bound.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `std::set`
Look at `std::set::lower_bound` and `std::set::upper_bound`

Comment: std::set is perfect for this situation. Thanks @dani

Answer (score 2):

You can use std::set here.
And for your functionality you can use functions upper_bound(i) and lower_bound(i) but catch here is they don't work similar to TreeSet.lower(i) and TreeSet.higher(i).

**lower_bound(const i)** – Returns An iterator to the the first element in the container which is not considered to go before i (i.e., either it is equivalent or goes after), or set::end if all elements are considered to go before i.

**upper_bound(const i)** – Returns an iterator to the first element in the container which is considered to go after i, or set::end if no elements are considered to go after i.

```
for (int i = 1; i<10; i++) myset.insert(i * 10); // 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90
int k = 50; 
set<int>::iterator itlow,itup;

itlow=myset.lower_bound (k);  
itup=myset.upper_bound (k);

if(itlow!=myset.begin()){
   itlow--;
   cout << *itlow;  // 40 will print
}
cout << *itup;  // 60 will print
```